Rope on Rope Dynamic simulation?
I have a question about how to create the rope dynamic simulation. The point represents more than 2 ropes laid down on each other with tight similar to this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JlK94Qw0vIY

Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external links may be helpful additions to questions they should not remain the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload images or gifs, besides thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be searched for and indexed thus helping future users find it.
